# ElasticSearch behaving different between cities

Tags: geojson, elasticsearch

I'm experiencing some very strange behavior from Elasticsearch. I am using **geo_bounding_box** to search the area visible in Google Maps. I have data in New York and San Fransisco. New York behaves as expected. San Fransisco does not, which is confusing me.

When searching in San Fransisco, I have to invert the longitude for east and west in order for data to be returned.

Searching in New York works just fine

[image: New York (Normal)]

```
// New York
"geo_bounding_box" : {
    "location.coordinates": {
        "top_right": [40.75595545633613,-73.85303608398436],
        "bottom_left": [40.64820096366504,-74.03156391601561]
    }
}
```

[image: San Fran (Normal)]

```
// San Fransisco (Normal)
"geo_bounding_box": {
    "location.coordinates": {
        "top_right": [37.79734048601642,-122.39438402099609],
        "bottom_left": [37.7692568462339,-122.4390159790039]
    }
}
```

[image: San Fran (Inverted)]

```
// San Fransisco (Swapped)
"geo_bounding_box": {
    "location.coordinates": {
        "top_right": [37.79734048601642,-122.4390159790039],
        "bottom_left": [37.7692568462339,-122.39438402099609]
    }
}
```

As you can see, swapping the longitude values returns results but it does not make any sense because we are searching outside of the bounding box.

I am using elasticsearch Version: 1.4.4

[EDIT]
This is an example of geo data stored in the San Fransisco area

```
"location": {
    "coordinates": [37.7876027, -122.4215609],
    "type": "Point"
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are putting coordinates into the array in the wrong order. The [order is [lon, lat]](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/query-dsl-geo-bounding-box-filter.html#_lat_lon_as_array_3), not [lat, lon].

So you probably wanted:

```
"geo_bounding_box": {
    "location.coordinates": {
        "top_right": [-122.39438402099609, 37.79734048601642],
        "bottom_left": [-122.4390159790039, 37.7692568462339]
    }
}
```

Also, it would be more conventional to do `top_left` and `bottom_right`...

Edit based your update to the question: The input coordinates also need to be in [[lon, lat] order for an array](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/lat-lon-formats.html). As noted in the guide, this is a common problem.

Comment: So I switch the lon and lat values and that does not work. Does the data need to be indexed this way? I added an example of how data is stored in the original post.

Comment: This also does not explain why data loads normally in NY and inverted in SF

Comment: Updated. As to why NY and not SF, its hard to say without seeing all the data. Perhaps the compound errors sometimes cancel, sometimes not.